# Get bash function path from name

Tags: bash, shell

A hitchhiker, waned by the time a function is taking to complete, wishes to find where a function is located, so that he can observe the function for himself by editting the file location. He does not wish to print the function body to the shell, simply get the path of the script file containing the function. Our hitchhiker only knows the name of his function, which is `answer_life`.

Imagine he has a function within a file `universal-questions.sh`, defined like this, the path of which is not known to our hitchhiker:

```
function answer_life() {
    sleep $(date --date='7500000 years' +%s)

    echo "42"
}
```

Another script, called `hitchhiker-helper-scripts.sh`, is defined below. It has the function above `source`'d within it (the hitchhiker doesn't understand `source` either, I guess. Just play ball.):

```
source "/usr/bin/universal-questions.sh"

function find_life_answer_script() {
    # Print the path of the script containing `answer_life`
    somecommand "answer_life" # Should output the path of the script containing the function.
}
```

So this, my intrepid scripter, is where you come in. Can you replace the comment with code in `find_life_answer_script` that allows our hitchhiker to find where the function is located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash operating in extended debug mode, `declare -F` will give you the function name, line number, and path (as sourced):

```
function find_life_answer_script() {
    ( shopt -s extdebug; declare -F answer_life )
}
```

Like:

```
$ find_life_answer_script
answer_life 3 ./universal-questions.sh
```

Running a sub-shell lets you set extdebug mode without affecting any prior settings.

Comment: Perfect answer. Not a big fan of switching `shopt` to then revert immediately, however. If that could be avoided, I'd prefer that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You can avoid the `shopt` toggle by running in a sub-shell. This has the advantage of not affecting any existing `extdebug` setting, at the cost of a sub-shell. Answer updated.

Comment: Fantastic idea! Would upvote twice if I could, thank you. Excellent commentary on the answer edits btw, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your hitchhiker can also try to find the answer this way:

```
script=$(readlink -f "$0")

sources=$(grep -oP 'source\s+\K[\w\/\.]+' $script)

for s in "${sources[@]}"
do
  matches=$(grep 'function\s+answer_life' $s)
  if [ -n "${matches[0]}" ]; then
    echo "$s: Nothing is here ("
  else
    echo "$s: Congrats! Here is your answer!"
  fi
done
```

This is for case if debug mode will be unavailable on some planet )

Comment: This is quite a nice answer! It has failed on one test I just performed (upon a sourced function, unfortunately too), although it works quite well for installations and packages. Obviously have to consider if my hitchhiker is too many light years away from the nearest `apt` server ¯\_(ツ)_/¯